# Assign tag to UIButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have this code in a for loop:

```
 //button Delete

        buttonDelete = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [buttonDelete addTarget:self 
                           action:@selector(deleteMessage:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [buttonDelete setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        buttonDelete.frame = CGRectMake(680, -1, 30.0, 30.0);

        buttonDelete.tag = i;

      NSLog(@"Tag: %d", buttonDelete.tag);

        [buttonDelete setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"deleteButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [image1 addSubview:buttonDelete];

        if (DeleteButtonArray == nil)DeleteButtonArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [DeleteButtonArray addObject: buttonDelete];


        //Button Delete
```

This code runs 9 times, so i increases (from 1 to 9). I know that i increases correctly because I assign in the same way a tag to an image, but for some reason the NSLog shows this:

```
Tag: 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3,...
```

So it arrives at 3 and restarts the count. Why?? Any ideas??

Comment: You didn't post the crucial parts - the loop and the initial declaration of `i`.

Comment: yes - show more code / the whole method..

Comment: +1 In addition, it's never a good idea to assign a tag of `0` as it's the default tag for all views created. You never know what you'll get.

Comment: I'm agree, the problem seems to be in your loop

Comment: do{
        
        NSArray *allKeys = [Dictionary allKeys];
        for (int i = 0; i < [allKeys count]; i++) {

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem: I just did like this:

```
z = z + 1;
        buttonDelete.tag = z;
```

with

```
z = 0;
```

in the view did load. I still can not understand why i didn't work, because I assign with i the tags to the images correctly, and I do it in the same way...